# How to retrieve the value of a field from a variable in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to use the value of a variable as the name field with a fetch()[0] function ?

My Collection :

```
db.Item.insert({
    "name" : "hello",
    "param1" : "ok",
    "param2" : "ok",
    "parma3" : "na",
    "parma3" : "ok"
});
```

Function :

```
 event() {
      var it = 'param2';
      return Item.find({svcPai : text}).fetch()[0].it;
 }
```

--> I want to return the value in param2 : **"ok"**

Comment: Have you tried `return Item.find({svcPai : text}).fetch()[0][it];`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the variable to access the key. I think you may have to do

```
event() {
    var it = 'param2';
    return Item.find({svcPai : text}).fetch()[0][it];
}
```

Comment: That exactly what I want ! Thanks :)